What pressure would the spring-contacting piston face experience?
I am trying to determine which pressure the spring-contacting piston face will experience. My assumption is that the pressure from the tube concentric with the spring will be the pressure used to determine the force preventing compression of the spring. The workings of oilfield hydraulics are still unclear to me. I am also assuming that the pressure in the beginning (L->R) of the piston bore will be the pressure acting on the opposite piston face. My goal is to compress the spring with the piston.

With only a partial image it's difficult to see what's what here. Is there hydraulic back-pressure or just the spring? Is there a schematic symbol to go with it?

Apologies, there will be hydraulic pressure supplied to the spring chamber by way of the ports in the rod. The system reflects an open-loop hydraulic setup if that is helpful.
